# Heroku Dashboard Metrics Web Dyno Error

Tags: heroku

Can anyone please tell me what the red icon means? And assuming it's not a good sign, what can I do to fix it? Thanks.

http://imgur.com/E5kY7A9

Comment: Did you try hovering over it? Or filign a support ticket? https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new

Comment: Yeah, I tried hovering over, but no message appears. It turned green a few minutes ago. I'll file a support ticket. New to Heroku, so thanks for the link.